# Generate a plain text file in Oracle Reports

Tags: oraclereports

I am using Oracle Reports but I cannot find a format which is similar to my needs. The closest is the Delimited data format but this leaves unnecessary spaces, tabs or symbols between columns. Is there a way to get this result but removing the unnecessary format

e.g. 
Column 1 would read A00000
and Column 2 would read BCD

I want to get 
A00000BCD rather than A00000 BCD which is what I am currently getting.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try deleting the space between Columns 1 and 2 in Layout Editor? What is the value of `DESFORMAT` parameter? Is the delimted report generated, the primary output (defined by `DESFORMAT`) or are you using some package like `TEXT_IO` to create the delimited file as a secondary output?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify my comment to your question.

Assuming your report makes use of the Layout Editor stuff [i.e., the delimited data is generated as directed by `DESFORMAT` and not by some custom packages], you have the following options:

1. Delete the unwanted spaces between the column fields in the Layout Editor.
2. Concatenate the columns in your Query and use it in a single field in the Layout Editor.

If [1] fails, try [2].

If you are using custom package, then it is really straightforward - remove/trim the spaces/tabs in the code.